# Javascript repeated .keyup(function(event) function for different inputs

Tags: javascript

I've created a small ajax suggestion input field (located here: https://github.com/joyser/suggestion/)

Javascript detects a keyup event in the suggestion box like this:

```
$("#suggestiveInput").keyup(function(event){

})
```

Where the input has an id of suggestiveInput.

I want to be able to have more than one suggestion box on the page, but would prefer not to have to use php to print $("#suggestiveInput").keyup(function(event){ for each element.

So ideally, I want one javascript function that'll handle all the inputs.

Also, I'd prefer not to capture all keystrokes and then route it to the text field if possible

I've tried something like this:

```
function suggestiveInput(inputName, options){

    suggestionCount++;
    $("#suggestiveInput"+suggestionCount).keyup(function(event){

    })

})
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a class for binding this?

Comment: Why does it not solve the problem? How are you calling that function?

Comment: Yeah, for this you could probably just add something like `class="suggestInput"` to each input that you want and then bind it to that class: `$('.suggestInput').keyup(function() {`

Comment: ah ok, and within the function how do i find the id of the input?

Answer (score 0):

Apply a class name to each input and then bind the keyup event to that. You can apply a class to multiple elements.